# How do I match a string pattern until that pattern stops occuring

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that has a specific pattern at the start, that I need to match until it stop occuring, meaning match pattern once until it's broken. The pattern is a digit(s) and a specific (d,h,m,s) character.

For example, `3days 50 seconds 10 min lorem ipsum consectetur adipiscing elit 24 sec sit ametelit` has to match `3days`, `50 seconds` and `10 min`, but not `24 sec` because it occurs after the pattern was broken.

I have already written a RegEx that matches a digit and character, `/\d{1,8}\s*(d|h|m|s)/g`. This will match a number of digits at the start, ignore whitespace and then check if a specific character occurs, so it returns these matches `3d`, `50 s` and `10 m`.

However, it matches *everything* that passes the test, even `24 s`, which I don't want it to do. If I remove `/g`, then it will expectedly return only the first result, which is also undesireable.

Comment: Should `3days 50 seconds 10 min  24 sec` match `3d 50s 10 m 24 s`? Or every time unit should occur only once?

Comment: is the "pattern broken" because seconds appear twice, or because there is content ("lorem ipsum...") between the sub-patterns?

Comment: Would `3days 50 sxwxwxw 10 min` be a valid pattern? Or is there a list of valid units like `[day, days, seconds, sec, secs, second, min, minute, minutes, ...]`

Comment: @Mulan The pattern is considered broken because there is content between the sub-patterns. The `24 s` can be discarded at that point.

Comment: @Konrad It shouldn't match `24 s`, because it occurs as a new pattern, after the previous one was broken (content in-between)

Comment: I think you will have less trouble if you specify all the possibly unit labels `const re = /(\d+\s*(days?|d|hours?|hr|h|minutes?|min|m|seconds?|sec|s)\s*)+/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const units = ['day', 'days', 'hour', 'hours', 'minute', 'minutes', 'min', 'mins', 'second', 'seconds', 'sec', 'sec']

const regexp = new RegExp(String.raw `(?:\d{1,2}\s*(?:${units.join('|')})\s+)+`, 'g')

const text = '3days 50 seconds 10 min lorem ipsum consectetur adipiscing elit 24 sec sit ametelit'

for (const match of text.matchAll(regexp)) {
  console.log(match)
}
```

You can also match any word

```js
const regexp = /(?:\d{1,2}\s*[a-z]+\s+)+/g

const text = '3days 50 seconds 10 min lorem ipsum consectetur adipiscing elit 24 sec sit ametelit'

for (const match of text.matchAll(regexp)) {
  console.log(match)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose there is no way around having to specify each unit invididually?

Comment: @Salthy: there is *perhaps* the option of using "[groups and backreferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet#groups_and_backreferences)," specifically this table-entry `\k<Name>` but I haven't learned the black arts necessary to use that approach as yet.